# Angular 2 redux and immutable.js state

Tags: angular, redux, immutable.js

I use ng2-redux and I'm trying to make redux state immutable. I can't do it because I don't know which interface is implemented by immutable state.

For example, I have a redux state:

```
let IState = {
    a: {
        b: string
    };
    d: string;
};

let state: IState  = {
  a: {
    b: 'c'
  },
  d: 'e'
}
```

Then immutable state is:

```
let immutableState = Immutable.fromJS(state);
```

Or maybe:

```
let immutableState = Immutable.Map(state);
```

I should know immutable state interface to work with redux:

```
constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IState>) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use generic Immutable.Map, You could use Immutable.js Record to create a class.

e.g.

```
// define an interface
interface IState = {
    a: {
        b: string
    };
    d: string;
};

// next, use the Record constructor passing in the defaults for the class
const stateRecord = Record({
  a: null,
  d: ''
});

// construct a class that extends the return from the Record call
export class MyState extends stateRecord implementsIState {
  a: Map<string, string>;
  d: string;
  constructor(config: IState) {
    super(config);
  }
}
```

Then in your NgRedux use the class you made.

```
constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<MyState>) { ...
```

Since you are extending the `stateRecord`, the class is immutable. More information on how Records work in the ImmutableJs docs at https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record